# Non-Integer input exception not being caught

Tags: c++, exception, runtime-error, try-catch

I am attempting to learn and create exceptions in C++, however only one catch is being used instead of the other for an exception from cin using ios::failbit.

The code below is just using integer division and creating throws when user inputs 0 to divide and when inputting a non-integer, such as a word.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int userNum;
   int divNum;
   int result;
   cin.exceptions(ios::failbit);       // Allow cin to throw exceptions

   try {
      
      cin >> userNum >> divNum;
      
      if (divNum <= 0) {
         throw runtime_error("Divide by zero!");
      }
      
         result = userNum / divNum;
         cout << result << endl;  
      
   }
   //why output is only printing RUNTIME EXCEPTION and will not print INPUT EXCEPTION?
   catch (const runtime_error &excpt) {
      cout << "Runtime Exception: " << excpt.what() << endl;
   }
   
   catch (const ios_base::failure &excpt) {
        cout<<"Input Exception: "<< excpt.what() << endl;
   }
   
   

   return 0;
}
```

The only problem the code is having when running is not picking the correct error when inputting a non-integer. Other than that all other tests run fine.

I have attempted removing const from both catches and issue persists.

Let me know what I should change to correct the code and any improvements you would also recommend.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because, since C++11, `ios_base::failure` inherits from `runtime_error` (via `system_error`) so your first `catch` catches `ios_base::failure` too.

The solution is to swap the order of your `catch`es so that the more generic `runtime_error` becomes the fallback.